# How to extract oval contours from an image and save into different variables?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mask

I need to extract the 12 oval shapes from the image and store them in separate variables say 1 to 12.
The original image was as follows

Original Image:

[image: Original Imge]

Output image:

[image: Output image]

Can someone help me extract all those oval shapes into different variables ?

my code is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

path = r'/home/parallels/Desktop/Opencv/data/test.JPG'
i = cv2.imread(path, -1)
img_rgb = cv2.resize(i, (1280,720))
cv2.namedWindow("Original Image",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img,9,105,105)

r,g,b=cv2.split(img)

equalize1= cv2.equalizeHist(r)
equalize2= cv2.equalizeHist(g)
equalize3= cv2.equalizeHist(b)
equalize=cv2.merge((r,g,b))
equalize = cv2.cvtColor(equalize,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

ret,thresh_image = cv2.threshold(equalize,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
equalize= cv2.equalizeHist(thresh_image)

canny_image = cv2.Canny(equalize,250,255)
canny_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(canny_image)
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(canny_image,kernel,iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours= sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
c=contours[0]
print(cv2.contourArea(c))

final = cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (255,0, 0), 3)
mask = np.zeros(img_rgb.shape,np.uint8)

new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[c],0,255,-1,)
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img_rgb, img_rgb, mask=equalize)

cv2.namedWindow("new",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("new",new_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. After obtaining your binary image, you can perform contour area + aspect ratio filtering. We can sort the contours in order from left-to-right using [`imutils.contours.sort_contours()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7). We [find contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) then filter using [`cv2.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea)
 and aspect ratio with [`cv2.approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) + [`cv2.arcLength`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#contour-perimeter). If they pass this filter, we draw the contours and append it to a `oval` list to keep track of the contours. Here's the results:

Filtered mask

[image]

Results

[image]

Isolated ovals

[image]

Output from `oval` list

```
Oval contours: 12
```

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours

# Load image, resize, convert to HSV, bilaterial filter
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
resize = cv2.resize(image, (1280,720))
original = resize.copy()
mask = np.zeros(resize.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(resize, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
hsv = cv2.bilateralFilter(hsv,9,105,105)

# Split into channels and equalize 
r,g,b=cv2.split(hsv)
equalize1 = cv2.equalizeHist(r)
equalize2 = cv2.equalizeHist(g)
equalize3 = cv2.equalizeHist(b)
equalize = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
equalize = cv2.cvtColor(equalize,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Blur and threshold for binary image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(equalize, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours, sort from left-to-right
# Filter using contour area and aspect ratio filtering
ovals = []
num = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    if area > 1000 and ar < .8:
        cv2.drawContours(resize, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        cv2.putText(resize, str(num), (x,y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,55,12), 2)
        ovals.append(c)
        num += 1

result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)
print('Oval contours: {}'.format(len(ovals)))

cv2.imshow('equalize', equalize)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('resize', resize)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```